# New to Java and having issues with which name/variable references

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've used this site searching for specific errors for two semesters now.  I know the question I am asking is more broad and basic than most of the things I've searched/read on this site, but this is the only place I have to turn for information outside of the classroom.

Right now I'm working on a simple Photo Calculator Phone application using Android Studio.  It has 3 radio buttons with each assigned a specific value.  I know there is something wrong with how I'm referencing each of the buttons and attempting to trigger a calculation.

Some of the current errors:

```
    Cannot resolve method'getText()'
    Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.editText','int'
    Operator "*" cannot be applied to 'double', 'andriod.widget.EditText'
```

Below is the code:

```
        package com.example.squirreloverlord.ccarringtonphonephotoprint;

    import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double small = 19;
    double medium = 49;
    double large = 79;
    double Result;
    double inputUser;
    double Number;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        final EditText inputUser = (EditText)     findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        final RadioButton radioButton4x6 = (RadioButton)     findViewById(R.id.radioButton4x6);
        final RadioButton radioButton5x7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5x7);
        final RadioButton radioButton8x10  = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton8x10);
        final TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        Button Calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);

        Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                inputUser=Double.parseDouble(Number.getText( ).toString(  ));
                DecimalFormat tenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

                if(radioButton4x6.isChecked( ))   {
                    if (inputUser <50) {
                        Number = small * inputUser;
                        Result.setText(tenth.format(Result) + " is your total cost!");

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter a value less than 50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
                if (radioButton5x7.isChecked( ))  {
                    if (inputUser <50) {
                        Number = medium * inputUser;
                        Result.setText(tenth.format(Result) + " is your total cost!");
                    }  else  {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter a value less than 50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                if (radioButton8x10.isChecked()) {
                    if (inputUser <50) {
                        Number = large * inputUser;
                        Result.setText(tenth.format(Result) + " is your total cost!");

                    }  else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter a value less than 50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: please can you explicitly include your question. you might have done it implicitly but i don't seem to understand what you really want.

Comment: Please stick to java naming conventions.  it is very difficult to understand your code when you mixing the cases for `variables`

Comment: Sorry I edited in the specific errors I am encountering.  First time making a post here, had some issues with the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should change the variable like this:

```
double inputUser;
```

and

```
final EditText inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
```

inputUser will get coufused about this code

```
inputUser=Double.parseDouble(Number.getText( ).toString(  ));
```

If i were you that i will change like this:

```
final EditText editUser= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);

editUser=Double.parseDouble(editUser.getText( ).toString(  ));
```

then like the code `editUser <50` it will get the value

Hope it helps.

According to your double prints, change like this:

```
prints=Double.parseDouble(editUser.getText( ).toString(  ));
```

then you can use if like this:

```
if (prints<50)
```

Comment: It cleared up the algorithm issues, but still having the getText issue. 

http://imgur.com/a/XoIOp

Comment: the getText() is for EditText not for Double when you input the number on the APP ,  you should change prints to editUser , then you will pass the compile

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise:

1. > Cannot resolve method'getText()'

mistake is because you called your double as `Number` after all there is a class `java.lang.Number` as well. So rename it to `number`

2. > Double.parseDouble(Number.getText( ).toString(  ));

Please, read carefully what do you try to do here - get double as String and parse it back to double... what is the reason to do that?

3. > Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.editText','int'
   >
   > Operator "*" cannot be applied to 'double', 'andriod.widget.EditText'

You defined a variable `inputUser` as an object of class `EditText` and then you try to apply primitive math operators `<` and `*` to it.

Fortunately Java is strictly typed language and cannot do that.
I'm not familiar with android packages. but perhaps EditText has something like `getText()` which you can parse to double and then compare or multiply...